# create sub domains "sub.example.com" with .net core 5

Tags: asp.net-mvc, .net-core

i'm trying to create a sub domain for my website, something like "sub.example.com", i've been following a tutorial on youtube but it is not working, this is what i have done.

my startup.cs

```js
 public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
     services.AddControllersWithViews();
            services.AddSingleton<SubdomainRouteTransformer>();
        }
    
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
                 app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
                {
                          endpoints.MapDynamicControllerRoute<SubdomainRouteTransformer>(
                          "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
                });

         public class SubdomainRouteTransformer: DynamicRouteValueTransformer
        {
     
            public override async ValueTask<RouteValueDictionary> TransformAsync(
                HttpContext httpContext,RouteValueDictionary values)
            {
                var host =httpContext.Request.Host.Value;
                var  subdomain = httpContext.Request.Host.Value.Split(".")[0];
     
               if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(subdomain)){
                   values["controller"]= subdomain;
               }
                return values;
            }
        }
```

program.cs

```js
        public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
                Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
                .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
                {
                    webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
                  webBuilder.UseUrls("https://*.localhost:5001");
                });
```

i have also registred new subdomains on my machine hosts file

```
127.0.0.1 admin.localhost
127.0.0.1 bugreport.localhost
```

i tried to create a break point on the TransformAsync method, it is getting hit by the compiler whenever i enter the normal URL address "https://localhost:5001".
when i enter sub domain address "https://admin.localhost:5001" TransformAsync method is never getting hit .

any help is appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i've figured out this by myself, it seams like the solution above is working perfectly, the issue was with Safari, somehow the solution above did not work on it but it worked perfectly on chrome.
also another small detail is that you can skip the last step of setting the host file on your machine, the solution works without it.